# Rotate string vertically in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

Good evening!

Is there a way to rotate a string vertically using PL/SQL procedure or function? 
I have found many solutions for getting something like

```
c
e
l
l
```

but i need a different result, like this one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywerX.jpg

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't do what you want only in pl/sql. that's an interface question. Developing an application?

Comment: A report... I am using BIRT, it has a plug-in for vertical text which creates an image for vertical text and it looks absolutely ugly when printed. It would be much easier and cleaner to get a report header using a report procedure... Too bad it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope this helps.

```
--Horizontal to vertical
SELECT SUBSTR(A.col1,LEVEL,1) str
FROM
  ( SELECT 'avrajit' col1 FROM dual
  )A
  CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(a.col1);


--Verticle to horizontal

SELECT listagg(A.col1) WITHIN GROUP(
ORDER BY a.col2) str
FROM
  (SELECT 'a' col1,1 col2 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'v' col1,2 col2 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'r' col1,3 col3 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' col1,4 col4 FROM dual
  )A;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need a bit different result) Like one on the image)

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to claim I understand this, but I combined and tweaked a couple of examples I found and arrived at this, for what its worth.  Hey, whadaya want for nuthin'?  lol

When run, it generates some HTML code.  Save that code into a file ending in .html and double-click to open in your browser.  You will see the output as you expect.  Maybe you can further tweak this to get what you expect?

This code:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select ''Cell'' from dual').transform(XMLType(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<html><head><style>
p {
    background-color: white;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
</style></head>
  <body>
   <table border="0">
     <tr bgcolor="white">
      <xsl:for-each select="/ROWSET/ROW[1]/*">
       <th><p><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></p></th>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </tr>
   </table>
   </body>
</html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>')).getclobval() as html from dual;
```

Generates this HTML (Press the "Run code snippet" button to see the output):

```html
<html><head><style>
p {
    background-color: white;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
</style></head><body><table border="0"><tr bgcolor="white"><th><p>Cell</p></th></tr></table></body></html>
```

So I doubt this helps you but it was interesting at any rate.

Comment: This is great solution!

Comment: True, this was so good... Thank you, this works in HTML, but does not with MS Word...

Comment: @alecsia You didn't say you needed it to work in MS word.

Comment: I did not know it wouldn't, unfortunately... The report designer doesn't recognize the "transform".

Answer (score 0):

you can use the negative position in the `substr`
If position is negative, then Oracle counts backward from the end of char.
[(see also doc.)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#SQLRF06114)

```
SELECT SUBSTR(str,0 - LEVEL,1) str
FROM
  ( 
    SELECT 'Cell' as str FROM dual  
  )
  CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(str)
;
```

Comment: But I don't need to split a word, I just need to rotate it by 90 degrees.